# NgXs dynamic selector: TypeError: Cannot read property 'x' of undefined

Tags: angular, ngxs

I'm trying to create a NgXs [dynamic selector](https://www.ngxs.io/concepts/select#dynamic-selectors), but I get the runtime error when the selector is used:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'x' of undefined
    at my-state.state.ts:56
    at wrappedSelectorFn (ngxs-store.js:2136)
    at memoized (ngxs-store-internals.js:58)
    at memoized (ngxs-store-internals.js:58)
    at Store.selectSnapshot (ngxs-store.js:2343)
    ...
```

The selector code:

```js
@State({ ... })
export class MyState {
    @Selector()
    static translations(lng: model.Language) {
        return createSelector([MyState], (state: MyStateModel) => {
            return state.translations[lng];
        });
    }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is the `@Selector()` decorator, which is intended to be used only with [lazy selectors](https://www.ngxs.io/concepts/select#lazy-selectors), but not dynamics. I removed the decorator and the problem was solved.

```js
@State({ ... })
export class MyState {
    // no decorators here
    static translations(lng: model.Language) {
        return createSelector([MyState], (state: MyStateModel) => {
            return state.translations[lng];
        });
    }
    ...
}
```